# Implement authentication with MagicCode

Tags: authentication, webhooks, one-time-password

I'm currently trying to build a new system that would mimic how you could log in on a smart TV with Netflix/AmazonPrime/Disney+ :

- A code is displayed on the device A.
- You enter this code on an authenticated device B.
- The Device A gets token so it could communicate as authenticated.
  The system looks like so:
  [image]
  **the code works like so**:
- The Device A call API route sending infos
- Auth service generate a MagicCode, saves infos with magic code as ID and returns MagicCode to Device A.
- Device B calls API route with MagicCode
- If magic code is still valid it returns the infos to Device B and Sends Auth Token to Device A

My problems are:

- I don't know how to send back the tokens to the device A. I can't call Device A since I have no idea how the network of this one will be configured. So **Device A must be the one calling**. The magic code can take up to few minutes to be entered in the Device B so wait for the answer of a standard HTTP call sounds risky as many layers in the infrastructure could just shot down the socket connection and lead to a time out.
  How could i manage that ?
- My magic code is generated usic cryptographic, it's the same algorithme as for a 6 digit OTP (one time password). For one time password, you generate with an ID and you check the validity with the same ID. Meaning you must have common ID value on both ends.In the case of my magic Code, I don't (that i know) have any common value on both devices so my magic code could just be a random string of 6 character it would be the same. It doesn't sound totally safe and 'im wondering if there is a better way to do this ?

Just for reference i'm using .Net but the question is broader that that.